# Sequelize query reply is: ,[object Object]

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

#### The function below worked but has broken without changes

```js
exports.updateFormState = async() => {
    let queryReply;
    try {
        queryReply = await db.sequelize.query(
            "SELECT * FROM stackoverflow"
        );
        console.log("Im passed the reply")
        console.log("This is the query: " + queryReply)
        if (queryReply[1] === 1) {
            console.log("Inside if statement")
            return "SUCCESS";
        }
    }catch(err) {
        return err.message;
    }
}
```

#### What it should do

It needs to fire the query to the database and return the results.

#### What it does

It returns ,[object Object]
The weird thing is that it always returned the right thing but now it doesn't

#### Things that work

The query works (Not shown in code)
The database connection is there
It worked before...

Comment: change the `console.log("This is the query: " + queryReply)` to `console.log("This is the query: " , queryReply)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snippet from the Sequelize docs:

> By default the function will return two arguments - a results array,
> and an object containing metadata (such as amount of affected rows,
> etc). Note that since this is a raw query, the metadata are dialect
> specific. Some dialects return the metadata "within" the results
> object (as properties on an array). However, two arguments will always
> be returned, but for MSSQL and MySQL it will be two references to the
> same object.

So, this will slightly depend on your underlying database of choice, but you're more than likely going to want to return `queryReply[0]` rather than `queryReply`.

Additionally, I note that you're doing this:

```
console.log("This is the query: " + queryReply)
```

This will attempt to render queryReply as a string, which it isn't, since it's an object. Instead, you might find it easier to debug using:

```
console.log("This is the query: ", queryReply)
```

Comment: This actually works thanks.
But I have used the ```console.log("This is the query: " + queryReply)``` before and that has worked. Would you know why?

Comment: My best guess would be that your environment has recently updated from a previous version of Sequelize to v2 or later. Please check out the changelog, and have a look at the notes for v2.0.0 when the .query() function was changed to return two params. :) Happy hacking.